# Forcing login on phpMyAdmin using cookies

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, phpmyadmin

Hello again StackExchange users. Todays problem is a little more complex then usual for my. I am developing a web based hosting panel for a server that my company just set up and they would like to manage web pages from the internet. The rest of the control panel is working great but this one third-party app is really bugging me, and that app is phpMyAdmin!

I want the user to be able to log into the "cPanel" of their website (note: we are not using cPanel or any previous software) and just click the phpMyAdmin link and be logged in already to their own specific database. When they login, I am passing their sql database account details into a cookie using the same encryption type that they have for phpMyAdmin. Viewing the cookie shows that the cookie is formatted correctly and they should be logged onto the system

The problem is when they click on the link to go to the phpMyAdmin page, they still get the login form even though the cookie is already set and appears to be correct. There is no error message or even a please relog in message with the system.

I have included my code for my CookieAuth class below so you guys can look at it. It's really frustrating since the cookies seem to be the only way I can log them in properly and there's not many documented examples on how to do this anywhere else.

```
class CookieAuth {
    private $_cookie_iv = null;
    public function createPMAsession($username, $password, $blowfish_key) {
        setCookie('pmaUser-1', $this->cookieEncrypt($username, $blowfish_key), time()+3600, "/phpmyadmin/");
        setCookie('pmaAuth-1', $this->cookieEncrypt($password, $blowfish_key), null, "/phpmyadmin/");
    }

    private function _useOpenSSL() {
        return (function_exists('openssl_encrypt') && function_exists('openssl_decrypt') && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes') && PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50304);
    }

    public function enlargeKey($key) {
        while(strlen($key) < 16) {
            $key .= $key;
        }
        return substr($key, 0, 16);
    }

    public function getMAC($key) {
        $length = strlen($key);
        if($length > 16) {
            return substr($key, 0, 16);
        }
        return $this->enlargeKey($length == 1 ? $key : substr($key, 0, -1));
    }

    public function getAES($key) {
        $length = strlen($key);
        if($length > 16) {
            return substr($key, 0, 16);
        }
        return $this->enlargeKey($length == 1 ? $key : substr($key, 0, -1));
    }

    public function cookieEncrypt($data, $key) {
        $mac = $this->getMAC($key);
        $aes = $this->getAES($key);
        $iv = $this->createIV();
        if($this->_useOpenSSL()) {
        $result = openssl_encrypt(
                $data,
                'AES-128-CBC',
                $key,
                0,
                $iv
            );
        } else {
            $cipher = new Crypt\AES(Crypt\Base::MODE_CBC);
            $cipher->setIV($iv);
            $cipher->setKey($aes);
            $result = base64_encode($cipher->encrypt($data));
        }
        $iv = base64_encode($iv);
        return json_encode(
            array(
                'iv' => $iv,
                'mac' => hash_hmac('sha1', $iv . $result, $mac),
                'payload' => $result,
            )
        );
    }

    public function getIVSize() {
        if($this->_useOpenSSL()) {
            return openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC');
        }
        $cipher = new Crypt\AES(Crypt\Base::MODE_CBC);
        return $cipher->block_size;
    }

    public function createIV() {
        if(!is_null($this->_cookie_iv)) {
            return $this->_cookie_iv;
        }
        if($this->_useOpenSSL()) {
            return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($this->getIVSize());
        } else {
            return Crypt\Random::string($this->getIVSize());
        }
    }

    public function setIV($vector) {
        $this->_cookie_iv = $vector;
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read my problem and I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: are you setting the cookie for the correct domain? i don't see any domain defined there, but in case the domain for phpmyadmin is different than the one for the so called cpanel

Comment: @tadman nothing that I am aware? Did you read the post? This adds the user and auth (password) for phpmyadmin account into cookies on their set path and encrypts them, but for some reason phpmyadmin will not log the users on automatically like it's supposed to. I included this code so you guys can see how I am doing it and tell me if I am missing something because it will not auto log the users in, they have to retype the details.

Comment: Also would like to add that this is indeed encrypting them properly as it creates a cookie for the username and when it takes you to the login page it has the username remembered on the form but its not logged in like I want it to be.

Comment: @rsz its a folder on their specific domain since the control panel is the same for every user on the server. its path is correct when viewing cookie data and is set the same way they set it via the CookieAuth script in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Kaboom You need to better define what your problem is and how someone can help you fix it. Right now I've got no idea what your actual issue is.

Comment: @tadman im not sure what else I can say if you don't understand my problem? I made a web based control panel. users connect to the panel to manage their websites. once they login to the panel they have options for managing their website. one of these options is to use phpMyAdmin to manage sql. phpmyadmin asks the user to login. it shouldnt. this script is supposed to pass the login details cookie for phpmyadmin but its not logging them in. this is the issue..

Comment: What you're *trying to do* is related to but different from the *problems you're having*. Can you boil this down to a **specific technical problem** with your code? Right now all I can see is you have some more work to do to figure out how the phpMyAdmin login system works so you can better integrate with it.

Comment: @tadman this system assigns the cookie pmaUser-1 and pmaAuth-1, which is the same thing that phpMyAdmin is using to register that you are logged in. By looking at their login script, it appears I am doing everything properly. yet for some reason, the logged in session just isn't there and wants me to login. By comparing the cookies from when i login with my portal and when I login with the phpMyAdmin login page, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the cookies and the code should be working but its just not. I don't know what the issue is exactly which is why Im here asking for help

Comment: I was hoping to do this exact same thing. The main advantage of using the cookie method over the signon method is that PMA will fall back to its own login page if no or invalid information is provided. Anyway, it [turns out](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blame/c9c659f28fbd6e06d7f7b68217705bee50b1591b/libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php#L654) that PMA uses a different, temporary, key to encrypt the password, which is stored in the PHP session. And yes, it looks like it's been like that for at least 4 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds exactly like what the auth_type signon was designed to address. Is there a particular reason you're not using that?

Failing that, the [documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#which-parameters-can-i-use-in-the-url-that-starts-phpmyadmin) shows how you can pass the username and password as part of the query string, which may not be ideal from a security standpoint, but might give you a starting place to make your modifications.

Have you tried POSTing the proper username and password directly to index.php? I'm not certain whether this will work because of the security token, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I missed the signon session key apparently in config. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great, I'm really glad that worked for you. Please drop a note on the developer list or in the issue tracker if there's anything specific that can be improved about the documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel really dumb now. Using signon session you have to declare the session variable for phpMyAdmin in your config. I was apparently unaware of this and upon changing this session variable I was able to single sign on users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **Signon authentication mode** using *signon.php* as documented in examples folder do not forget to change the auth_type in config.inc.php

Change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

To
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'signon';`

Also add the following

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'SignonSession';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL']     = 'examples/signon.php';
```